# How can I make my EF4 entities use the datetime2 type with SQL Server CE 3.5?

Tags: entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce, datetime2

I would like to store DateTime values using the datetime2 type in SQL Server CE 3.5.

If this is possible, how would I change my entity data model? I've tried editing it manually and Visual Studio refuses to show it in the designer afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datetime2 does not exist is SQL Server Compact, in order to save datetime2 values, you must save in a nvarchar(27) value of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn'
(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171931.aspx)

Comment: Does it make more sense to have two fields: datetime (for YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) and int (for milliseconds)? You can join them in UI, but such structure has smaller size and smaller index.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it does, the format above can be easily converted back to datatime2 on the server, that is less easy if it is split..

Answer (score 1):

If you take care about size of your database (especially if you've got indexes on this field), you can use a different approach.

Keep in the database two fields **datetime** (for *YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss*) and **smallint** (for *milliseconds*). And join them to get a proper DateTime before displaying in UI.

In this case size of these fields will be 10 bytes (according to [this source](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/sql-server-data-type-reference), *8 bytes* of datetime + *2 bytes* for smallint). Size of *nvarchar(27)* is 54 bytes.

Comment: Sql ce does not have smalldatetime